# Чтение и сортировка JSON в 200К

Tags: json, swift, xcode, сортировка, методы

Есть задача прочитать и отсортировать по алфавиту JSON в чуть более 200к записей.

1. Как можно быстро его прочитать?
2. Каким образом его можно отсортировать с наименьшими затратами во времени?

Для Хранения данных использую структуру. для сортировки использовал sort(), но с увеличением размера массива скорость сортировки падает.

Comment: Как насчёт использовать для хранения такого количества данных более подходящие инструменты? Да хоть тот же sqlite

Comment: Нет, в том то и соль что для хранения волнительные средства использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю вы храните массив структур, что-то подобное:

```
struct ServerObj: Codable {
    //....
}
var serverData: [ServerObj]
//....
serverData.sort { /* код сортировки */ }
```

Если я прав, то поменяйте структуру на клас, это уберет операции копирования ваших структур при сортировке (будут копироватся ссылки, что в разы быстрее чем пересоздание структур), ето должно ускорить сортировку в целом. Плюс если посмотреть документацию метод `sort()` работает за `O(n log n)` время и является лучшим временем для сортировки сравнением.

Для чтения есть вариант писать джейсон в файл и читать его построчно(по разделителю) и думаю это тоже должно упростить задачу